# How do you ban someone from a LAN world in Minecraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My sister keeps joining my Local Area Network world, hacking to give herself Operator status, and blowing up my stable (killing the donkeys, mules, and horses). Is there a way I can ban her?

Comment: Just don't open your game to LAN? And I highly doubt she's "hacking" to get OP, you probably just enabled it.

Comment: Im curious as to why you have a LAN server up, are you playing with someone else?

Answer (score 3):

```
/ban <username>
```

If this doesn't work (because it might be different in LAN worlds than on servers), then there's no way. Just don't open your game to LAN or don't connect to the same network that she's in.

Answer (score 0):

I always just like to disconnect and switch the multiplayer settings to invite only. This way only players that you let join can join, but I think this only works on iPads and tablets and stuff like that.